# Do nothing when condition is met

Tags: solidity

Can I do something like this in solidity? Will the user be able to do anything malicious?

```
 if(some condition met){
       //Do nothing or return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is no code inside and below that `if` statement, then the user cannot do anything malicious.

Given the following smart contract with a `checkCondition` function that checks a condition but does nothing else:

```js
contract TestContract {

    uint256 public id = 5;
    
    function checkCondition() public view {

        if(id == 5) {

        }

    }

}
```

There is nothing malicious anybody can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, that code is compilable and there is nothing malicious that the users can do with that function.

Using [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/), you can easily compile the code and check the errors.